# strange behavior of flume-ng

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

I am trying to aggregate apache web server logs into the hdfs using flume-ng..but strangely I am getting only first few rows into the hdfs..more strangely every time I start the agent two files are getting created and the second file is always smaller than the first one. My agent conf file looks like this:

```
agent1.sources = tail
agent1.channels = MemoryChannel-2
agent1.sinks = HDFS

agent1.sources.tail.type = exec
agent1.sources.tail.command = tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log.1
agent1.sources.tail.channels = MemoryChannel-2

agent1.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemoryChannel-2
agent1.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
agent1.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/flume
agent1.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.file.Type = DataStream

agent1.channels.MemoryChannel-2.type = memory
```

Also I am not getting any error message on the terminal..Is it normal or some mistake from my part??